# Use one entity with multiple databases in spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, entity-framework, jpa, entity, spring-data

Suppose, i have two database "DB1" and "DB2", both databases have same table called "A".

I have created two entityManagerFactories and two datasources for these databases.

- How can i create only one entity "A", and specify it in both entityManagerfactories?
- Is it possible to create two jparepositories using this entity and mention the package name in @EnableJpaRepositories along with entityMangerRef?

I tried this, but i am getting data only from a database. I am using spring-data-jpa.

Comment: I have implemented it refering the below link. http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/